# HTML/CSS formatting

Tags: html, css

I'm having to issues lining up items properly in my html code. I am not sure why they are not lining up the way I want them to. I didn't design this site I am just adding to it. Also this a word press page and I don't have access to change the site wide css so I was using inline css because `<style>` tags go in the page header which I don't have access to. Sorry I should have pulled the CSS out before posting the question so it was easier to follow. But I'm a programmer not a web designer, I don't always remember that you shouldn't use ids multiple times.

The first problem, I am having is lining up 4 items on my website. I have 2 text strings and image and a horizontal rule. I want the first string justified left, the second string justified right with the image to it's right. I then want the `<hr>` to be right under that. I tried to do this by putting the first string in on div and the second string with the image in another a separate div. What I am got was 3 lines. The first string justified left on one line. The second string justified right with the image on the second line and the `<hr>` on the line below. I have tried playing with different alignment settings in html attributes and in css but I cannot seem to get rid of the line break after the first string. What am I missing? I know this should be simple? Could it be the wordpress css?

my second problem is similar. I have a table cell with an image in it (x in a box). I can get the image to justify right but I'm having a problem getting it to vertically align to the top of the td. What am I missing?

Here's some example html: Is this easier to follow?

CSS:

```
table#one {
    width=900px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
div#div1 {
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    font-weight: bolder; 
    padding: 0px;
}
td#td1 {
    border: none; 
    background-color: #f8d3cf; 
    width:125px; 
    height:80px; 
    border-spacing: 10px; 
    padding:0;
}
div#div2 {
    padding:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
a#a1 {
    padding: 0px;
}
img#img1 {
    padding: 0px;
}
td#td3 {
    border: none; 
    width:10px;
}
td#td4 {
    border: none; 
    font:.6em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    width:125px; 
    height:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="one">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="div1">My Color Library</div>
            <div align="right" class="removeall">
                <a href="colors">
                    <img src="http://www.2100computerlane.net/workingproject/images/x-button.png" />
                    <bold>&nbsp;Remove All</bold>
                </a>
            </div>
            <HR/>
            </p>
            <div class="mycolor">
                <table><!--width="900px"  -->
                    <tr>
                        <td id='td1' align="right" valign="top"><a href="f8d3cf" id="a1"><img src="http://www.2100computerlane.net/workingproject/images/x-button.png" /></a></div></td>

                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td  id="td4">Desert Warmth<br/>70YR 56/190 A0542</td>                                                  
                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Some tips: 1) remove all inline CSS and work like you life in 2012 :); 2) use 1 html element per page; 3) use lower-case tagnames; 4) do not use tables for the lay-out.

Comment: With these tips your code would be: 1) more structured; 2) better HTML; 3) easier to maintance; 4) more modern; 5) more understandable for browsers.

Comment: @WouterJ is right. You can hardly expect help with code this difficult to read.

Comment: I know how to put stuff in css file and include it but my Css file is pages long and would just complicate this.

Comment: @Codeguy007 if you don't want help, don't ask questions. The lay-out is what you see on the page, if you want something different on the page you should redesign your lay-out. I don't see what other tips/answers you want? PS: I was the one of the 2 who downvoted this question.

Comment: Again, why do you have more than one `<html>` tag within a single page?

Comment: So you did. There are still a ton of problems, though, including the re-use of `id`s.

Comment: @Codeguy007 You have a `<div>` in a `<p>`, which is invalid and web-browsers will not allow this structure. Paragraphs may contain only inline content.

Comment: I'm not sure I know why that's a problem but it isn't causing my issues.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BrR2c/1/

Comment: I removed the extraneous <p>

Comment: @Codeguy007 you have still a lot of closing tags which don't have a begintag. It's a good practice to go through all your code, formats it the correct way and see what kind of errors there are, maybe the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will help you.  I have formatted the code correct right now for the second time, could you please be a little more polite and do it yourself the next time? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for that but I didn't even write most of the code. It's a hacked up dreamweaver special with way too many tables. I have a deadline so I don't have the luxury of redesigning the site by hand right now nor access to a good wysiwyg editor. To be honest I never noticed the orphan close tags but that could be because I pulled it out of a larger page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first issue, in your code you have two DIV elements:

```
<div id="div1">My Color Library</div>
<div align="right" class="removeall">
    <a href="colors">
        <img src="images/x-button.png" />
        <bold>Remove All</bold>
    </a>
</div>
```

DIV's are block-level elements, which means that adjacent DIV's are stacked vertically. So, the gap below the title is actually the area of the second DIV.

I believe you want this:

```
<div id="div1">
    My Color Library
    <div class="removeall">
        <a href="colors">
            <img src="images/x-button.png" />
            <bold>Remove All</bold>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.removeall {
    float: right;    
}
```

So, just place the second DIV inside the 1. DIV, and float it to the right.

Regarding your second issue, this CSS should do the trick:

```
#td1 {
    vertical-align: top;
}

#td1 img {
    vertical-align: top;   
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BrR2c/12/show/

Comment: It's the image in the td Xarcell suggestion moves it up but not all the way to the top.

Comment: @Codeguy007 I see. What are the dimensions of that image? Do you want it laid out like so - http://jsfiddle.net/BrR2c/6/ - (it's the red box in the demo, I gave it 16x16 dimensions).

Comment: No the I had modified the source to point at the image but someone edited it with a older version of the code. http://www.2100computerlane.net/workingproject/x-button.png is the image and it goes to the right of the link. But that's not the problem it's also in the colored table cell and needs to be in the top right hand corner. It's close now but not quite there.

Comment: @Codeguy007 That link is dead.

Comment: Oh btw your suggestion works in jsfiddle but not on the website. It wraps underneath  --- http://www.2100computerlane.net/workingproject/session-test.php

Comment: @Codeguy007 You have to also add the CSS, and make sure that it applies to the second DIV.

Comment: @Codeguy007 I've updated my answer with a solution to issue 2.

Comment: Ah, I must have forgotten to add that. It works now. Thanks a ton.